# Can't find configuration file: [ footprint_cartridge_conf.xml ]

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, odata

I am trying to install the XPM Session Preview Web Service on a Java app container (Tomcat 6.0).  To make the job easier I am using the pre-packaged WAR file which comes with the product install files: `\Tridion 2013 SP1\Content Delivery\roles\preview\webservice\java\webapp\cd_preview_webservice.war`

I have verified that my `cd_..._conf.xml` files are correct by taking the working ones from the Tridion Reference Implementation Staging site `bin/config` directory.  However, the webservice does not start up, and the logs show the following error:

> 2014-11-12 11:16:44,191 ERROR AmbientDataContext - A
>   ConfigurationException occurred while loading cd_ambient_conf.xml!
>   com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find
>   configuration file: [ footprint_cartridge_conf.xml ]  at
>   com.tridion.configuration.XMLConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(XMLConfigurationReader.java:92)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataConfig.getCartridgeConfigurations(AmbientDataConfig.java:400)
>   ~[cd_ambient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataConfig.initializeConfiguredClaimScopes(AmbientDataConfig.java:149)
>   ~[cd_ambient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataConfig.(AmbientDataConfig.java:139)
>   ~[cd_ambient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataConfig.getAmbientDataConfig(AmbientDataConfig.java:185)
>   ~[cd_ambient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataContext.(AmbientDataContext.java:30)
>   ~[cd_ambient.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext.(WebContext.java:15)
>   [cd_ambient.jar:na]   at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter.init(AmbientDataServletFilter.java:111)
>   [cd_ambient.jar:na]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4076)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4730)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>   [catalina.jar:6.0.39]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_23]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.6.0_23]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_23]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>   [bootstrap.jar:6.0.39]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   [bootstrap.jar:6.0.39] 2014-11-12 11:16:44,192 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context:
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext

I've validated that my configs are correct as mentioned above, and have done the usual Google and checked this site for possible answers.  What's missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the pre-packaged WAR file missing the `cd_preview_web.jar`.  Simply copy this Jar from the install location's lib folder to your app's deployment location.